# CRM Report (SSRS) Body Disappears When Zooming, Using Toolbar In IE

Tags: internet-explorer, reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011, zooming

I made a SSRS sql report and uploaded into CRM 2011 report solution. Things were all good until I discovered that when using the zoom tool in the CRM report toolbar in IE, the report content disappears. Neither Chrome or Firefox have this zoom tool in the tool bar. Anyway my main browser is IE.

When zoom is 100% it looks great.  When it is 200% I cannot see the top half of the report.  When I change to zoom 500% report content totally disappears.

How do I keep it from disappearing?

[image: partially disappeared report]

Comment: Any idea? this is going to be a big issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have installed the CRM 2011 RU 18 and this issue is working fine.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44265